# Tracking Yard Signs

Tags: groups, tags, civicampaign

Just getting started with CiviCRM and got my voter registration list imported and created contacts.  Now we are getting requests for political yard signs coming in.  What would be easiest way to track this?  As tags, group, or create something in CiviCampaign?

James

Comment: Andy's answer is what I would do too - but it would help to know what you intend to do with the information to ensure that answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a new activity type called ' Yard Sign' with associated custom fields. See below for an example:
[image]

Comment: Yep, agree, Activity.

Comment: Thank you Andy, I gave it a try and it will work well.